# When I try to sum csv file using pandas it does not work

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I am new to pandas and I try to sum my csv file. I have created my csv which has Country and Count column and use pandas to sum the total count of each country. I am also not sure about my csv format wether I converted correctly or not. This is my code

```
import pandas as pd
df =pd.read_csv ("/Users/mani/Desktop/finalgeocount.csv")
print df.groupby(['COUNTRY']).sum()
```

This is my raw csv file data

```
COUNTRY COUNT

China   1
China   1
China   1
China   2
Ireland 1
China   3
Moldova 1
```

I need the output like this:

```
China           8
Ireland         1
Moldova         1
```

But my output is showing like below:

```
                            Unnamed: 2  Unnamed: 3  Unnamed: 4
COUNTRY                                                       
Albania                            NaN         NaN         NaN
Algeria                            NaN         NaN         NaN
Angola                             NaN         NaN         NaN
Anguilla                           NaN         NaN         NaN
```

Comment: What's the output of df.columns?

Comment: Your code should work. What is the exact problem?

Comment: @TedPetrou I have updated my current ouput in my post. Please check

Comment: Your csv file is ilformatted. That comma after Moldova is messing it up. Needs quotes around entire name

Comment: @TedPetrou Still the same output. And I have lots of country data but only 10 of them are displaying and it does not calculate the count

Comment: The data you show is not csv, but rather fixed width data. Is this your raw data, or did you format it in the post? Can you post some raw data?

Comment: @Danny_ds I have updated the raw data in my post. Please check

Comment: @Danny_ds I can print using the pandas but my output shows only the half country like this. Congo, The Democratic Republic of the       2
Costa Rica                                 10
...                                       ...
Seychelles                               1722
Singapore                                 172
Sint Maarten (Dutch part)                   1

Comment: Do you mean some names are truncated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The raw data that you've posted is tab delimited, which is a form of CSV. When reading the file it helps to specify the delimiter:

```
>>> df = pd.read_csv('/Users/mani/Desktop/finalgeocount.csv', delimiter='\t')
>>> df
   COUNTRY  COUNT
0    China      1
1    China      1
2    China      1
3    China      2
4  Ireland      1
5    China      3
6  Moldova      1
>>> df.groupby('COUNTRY').sum()
         COUNT
COUNTRY       
China        8
Ireland      1
Moldova      1
```

N.B. I had to tidy up the raw data a little to remove some stray characters from the second blank line.